# how to disable "Load on Demand" on a tree?

Tags: java, tree, zk

I'm trying to implement a filter for a `tree` and for that i need to browse all the `tree elements` and compare their `label` with the `value` from the `textBox filter`. The problem is if I want to access to all the `Treeitems` of the `tree` I need to disable the **`Load on demand`** and i don't know how to do it. 
Any suggestions? *I'm working with `richlet`.*

Answer (score 0):

I think the property is render on demand, you can disable it from your whole app, or from a component in specific, check this:

[Client render on demand](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/Performance_Tips/Client_Render_on_Demand)

[Turn on Render on demand](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/Performance_Tips/Listbox,_Grid_and_Tree_for_Huge_Data/Turn_on_Render_on_Demand)

Answer (score 0):

You could expand everything, what means it has to be rendered :

```
public void fullyExpandTree(Component root){
    doCollapseExpandAll(root, true);
}


private void doCollapseExpandAll(Component component, boolean aufklappen) {
    if (component instanceof Treeitem) {
        Treeitem treeitem = (Treeitem) component;
        treeitem.setOpen(aufklappen);
    }
    Collection<?> com = component.getChildren();
    if (com != null) {
        for (Iterator<?> iterator = com.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            doCollapseExpandAll((Component) iterator.next(), aufklappen);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I don't wan't to expand all the `Tree`, just have the possibility to iterate all the `TreeItems`.
But I tried to work with the `TreeModel` and then notify the `Tree` and it resolve my issue.